# UIScrollView isDragging returns YES when no scrollview is decelerating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I want to know if a `UIScrollView` (`UITableView`) is dragging (panning) because the user's finger is actively panning it (the user's finger is on the scrollview . i.e. on the screen) or because the scroll view was "flicked" and it is scrolling (i.e 'decelerating' per UIScrollView default behavior)

I tried checking for

```
[self.tableView isDragging]
```

and unfortunately this returns '`YES`' in both cases

Then how can I decide if the user's finger is on the 'screen' - and panning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `isDragging` use `isTracking` for touch recognising on `UITableView`.

Or

if you want to recognize dragging of`UITableview` use scrollview delegate methods.

Answer (score 2):

Using your scroll view delegate you are achieve this.

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
 - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;   
// called on finger up as we are moving

 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; here
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using uiscrollView Delegate. You will get call here when user is panning

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
```